# Pages: Make auto dash to break a word to new line (hyphenation-Greek)

Tags: pages

How can I make Pages to auto-correct my text at the end of the line and break the last word to fill all the line like LaTex does. I have Hyphenation check but when I writing greek it doesn't working...

For example:

> Once in a while we all need some kind of document, it may be a busi- 
>   ness plan presentation....(continue)

Comment: Are you just asking how to turn on hyphenation?

Comment: Yes!!! I didn't that it called hyphenation! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has never provided any spellcheck or related tools for Greek in OS X.  You have to try 3rd party tools, like the ones mentioned at

https://discussions.apple.com/message/15810593#15810593

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer but I have already install it but I suppose that this I downloaded it doesn't support hyphenation...

Comment: @duke2311  Too bad.  If you find something that does work the way you want, let us know.